# How to get child Kendo Grid reference?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid as listed below. There is checkbox in each parent row. On a button click, I need to get the child grid of all parent rows for which checkbox is checked.  How can we do that?

Button Move

```
  $('#btnMove').click(function ()
        {
            var parentgrid = $('#sampleGrid').data('kendoGrid');
            var childGrid = $('#sampleGrid').closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");

            var Count = $('#sampleGrid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total();
            alert(Count);



            $(".chk").each(function ()
            {

                debugger;
              var tr=  $(this).closest("tr");
              var itemParentRow = parentgrid.dataItem(tr);

              //var childGrid = $(this).closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
            });

        });
```

Parent Grid

```
  $("#sampleGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                //type: "json",
                type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
                transport: {
                    read: "Home/GetCostPageData",
                    dataType: "json"
                    //,type: "POST"
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Program: {
                                type: "string",
                                //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
                                editable: false
                            },
                            Group: { type: "string" },
                            Sequence: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    total: "Total",
                    data: "CostPages"
                },
                pageSize: 25,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverGrouping: true,
                requestStart: function (e) {
                    Logger.logMessage("request started");
                },
                requestEnd: function (e) {
                    Logger.logMessage("request ended");
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    var data = this.data();
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            },
            detailInit: detailInit,
            dataBound: function ()
            {
                //this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            height: 500,
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            groupable: true,
            columns: [
                         {
                             field: "Recon",
                             title: "Select",
                             "template": "<input class='chk' type=\"checkbox\" />",
                             width: 25

                         },
                        {
                            field: "Program",
                            title: "Program",
                            width: 100
                        },

                        {
                            field: "Group",
                            title: "Group",
                            width: 100
                        },

                        {
                             field: "Sequence",
                             title: "Sequence",
                             width: 100
                        },
                         {
                             field: "Description",
                             title: "Description",
                             width: 100
                         }

            ],
            editable:
            {
                mode: "inline"
                //inline/incell/popup
            },

            toolbar: ["create"],
            edit: function (e) {
                if (!e.model.isNew()) {
                    // Disable the editor of the "id" column when editing data items
                    var numeric = e.container.find("input[name=id]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
                    numeric.enable(false);
                }
            },
            cancel: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }


        });
```

Child Grid

```
 function detailInit(e) {

        var myPerson = {};;
        myPerson.FirstName = "A";
        myPerson.LastName = "B";

        var id = e.data.uid;

        $("<div  id =" + id + "/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
                transport: {

                    dataType: "json",
                    //type: "POST",
                    read: {
                        url: "Home/GetItemsData",
                        data: function () {

                            return myPerson;
                        }
                    }

                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            Program: {
                                ItemID: "number",
                            },
                            ItemDescription: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    },
                    total: "Total",
                    data: "Items"
                },
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                pageSize: 5
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                        { field: "ItemID", title: "Item Id", width: "70px" },
                        { field: "ItemDescription", title: "Item Description", width: "110px" }
            ]
        });
    }
```

Comment: You want to find which `Parent` grid `checkbox` is checked on button click is that right?

Comment: @Jaimin. Yes And I want to find the corresponding to child grid too

Comment: i just post my code in demo link please close `html` and `css` tab so you can see demo perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple grids with the same button action being generated, the following will give you the grid id for the corresponding button.

```
$(".k-grid-add-new").bind('click', function () {       
    var strGridID =  this.closest('div.k-grid').id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code i have `checkbox` in `header` not in `td` but this help you to find corresponding `child grid`  `checkbox` to,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Submit1').click(function () {

                        var grid = $("#grid12").data("kendoGrid");
                        var selected = grid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').is(':checked');
                        var checkid = grid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq').attr('id');
                        var cellIndex = grid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq:checked').parent().index();
                        var rowIndex = grid.tbody.find('td').find('.chkbxq:checked').parent().parent().index(); 

 if (selected == true) {
                $('.k-detail-row').find('td.k-detail-cell').find('div.k-grid').find('table').find('tbody').find('td').find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
            }


});
});
</script>
```

This is demo link http://jsbin.com/ivoqup/3/edit

Comment: Did you find how to refer to the detail grid, for example if I want to set some values to selected row in the child grid?